# GROUP_CONCAT режет символы до 1024

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

куда вставить в этом коде SET SESSION group_concat_max_len=4294967295;
чтобы не резал до 1024?

```
$db = JFactory::getDbo();
        $query = $db->getQuery(true);
        $query->select('GROUP_CONCAT( e.id SEPARATOR "-jaex-") AS eid, GROUP_CONCAT( e.name SEPARATOR "-jaex-") AS ename, g.id AS gid, g.name AS gname ' );
        $query->from($db->quoteName('#__k2_extra_fields', 'e'));
        $query->join('LEFT', $db->quoteName('#__k2_extra_fields_groups', 'g'). 'ON (' . $db->quoteName('e.group') . ' = ' . $db->quoteName('g.id') . ')');
        $query->group('gid');
        $db->setQuery($query);
```

Comment: выполнить отедльным запросом?

Comment: Причём в том же соединении.

Comment: Выполняю. Почему-то не изменяется.